# Отсутствует экземпляр. Пишет что функция не соответствует перегруженой. Помогите сделать ее работающей.

Tags: c++, c++11, итераторы, шаблоны-с++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


template <typename FordIter1, typename FordIter2,
    typename FordIter3, typename Input>
Input function (FordIter1 const a, FordIter2 const b,
        FordIter3 const c);



int main()
{   
    vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
    vector<int> w = { 1,1,3,2,7,8,2,4 };
    vector<int> res;
    res = function(v.begin(), v.end(), w.begin());
    for (int i(0); i < res.size(); i++)
        cout << res[i];

    return 0;
}
template <typename FordIter1, typename FordIter2,
    typename FordIter3, typename Input>
Input function (FordIter1 const a, FordIter2 const b,
    FordIter3 const c)
{
    template <typename T, typename R>
    inline bool less(T const a, R const b)
    {
        return a < b;
    }
    vector<auto> res;
    for (auto it = a, it2 = c; it != b; it++, it2++)
    {
        if (less(*it, it2))
            res.push_back(*it);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Компилятору неоткуда вывести тип `Input` возвращаемого функцией значения (строка `res = function(v.begin(), v.end(), w.begin());`) — укажите его явно (`res = function<коль вы запихали Input в конец списка, извольте перечислить здесь все параметры шаблона>(v.begin(), v.end(), w.begin());`). Затем, откуда компилятор выведет тип из `auto` в строке `vector<auto> res;`?

Answer (score 1):

[Так](https://ideone.com/jiPkvn) не устроит?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename Iter>
    vector<typename iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type>
    function(Iter a, Iter b, Iter c)
{
    vector<typename iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type> res;
    for (; a != b; a++, c++)
    {
        if (*a < *c)
            res.push_back(*a);
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
    vector<int> w = { 1,1,3,2,7,8,2,4 };
    vector<int> res;
    res = function(v.begin(), v.end(), w.begin());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < res.size(); i++)
        cout << res[i] << endl;
}
```

Но, пожалуй, лучше не привязываться к вектору:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename Iter1, typename Iter2, typename OutIter>
void  function(Iter1 a, Iter1 b, Iter2 c, OutIter d)
{
    for (; a != b; a++, c++)
    {
        if (*a < *c)
            *d++ = *a;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
    vector<int> w = { 1,1,3,2,7,8,2,4 };
    vector<int> res;
    function(v.begin(), v.end(), w.begin(), back_inserter(res));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < res.size(); i++)
        cout << res[i] << endl;
}
```